# Smokes from potentiometer when trying the LCD project pi-3

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to set up the LCD with raspberry pi 3. These are the items in the circuit:

- Raspberry Pi 3 (RPi3) Model B (CanaKit)
- Potentiometer 10 K sold by Elegoo (Mega 2560 Project)
- DHT11
- LCD1602 Module (with pin header)

The following picture shows the circuit:

[image]

The display worked properly when I powered it on. I had to add the potentiometer as the contrast was very bad without it. I tried adding some resistors in series from the anode to 5v but it does not improve the contrast only increases/decreases the brightness.

My questions are:

1. How to improve this circuit (Running this without powering it off for days without worrying about the smoke issue)
2. Is my potentiometer bad? How can I fix this?
3. What's the ideal resistor replacement for the potentiometer? Is there anyway I can control the contrast programmatically?

Comment: Maybe you want to describe the *smoking* issue in a little more detail.  I think you are making some serious mistakes WRT to powering with 5V but presuming 3.3V logic.  Are you sure you can do that with a DHT11? Or the LCD?  If not, you may wreck the pi.

Comment: The smoke comes out of the potentiometer after I run a python program to display something and adjust the knob of potentiometer to change the contrast. It seems that the smoke comes even if there is not dht11. I followed this tutorial to wire it up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVdSc8VYVBM

Comment: Here my follow up question? If I don't use the potentiometer, and connect it to 3.3v and I can add resistor instead of grounding the contrast pin? If so would the characters be visible?

Comment: I don't watch videos in this context but I would double check your information.  5V devices may often work with the pi, and in theory there's no risk to the pi if the connections are all inputs to the device -- which I think is the case with the LCD, but not the DHT11.  I have a similar LCD and a DHT22 and I've never noticed any indication that their TTL level would be anything different than the supply voltage.  The DHT22 works fine with a 3.3V supply.  If the DHT11 is okay that way, that's how you should use it.

Comment: So, is the DHT11 the cause of this smoke? If I connect it to 3.3v, the smoke in potentiometer wont be an issue? (Sorry, I don't have much electrical background)

Comment: I'd guess the cause of the smoke in the potentiometer is a short circuit when you move it to one of the extremes of its travel.

Comment: But only then the contrast is proper. How to fix this?

Comment: The picture may show your circuit but it is very hard to tell what is connected to what. If you can give details on how the potentiometer is connected the reason for the smoke can be worked out.

Comment: This is how its connected: http://www.rototron.info/wp-content/uploads/LCD-Display02.jpg

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I solved it by connecting a 1k resistor from the contrast pin to the ground. And also 1k resistor between the anode and +5V.

Comment: Congratulations on solving it. As always, remember that **smoke = bad**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by connecting a 1k resistor from the contrast pin to the ground. And also 1k resistor between the anode and +5V. Now the contrast is perfect and no more smokes and removed the potentiometer!